# Unable to create an anchor for the h1 tag

Tags: css, html

I have an h1 tag:

```
<h1 id="something">
  My header
</h1>
```

I wonder, why doesn't it work as anchor? When I go to "localhost:3000/#something", it doesn't scroll down the page to the point where the h1 is located.

Comment: try setting `margin-top:600px;` to your `h1` tag and see if it scrolls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works. Posibly your `h1` is not low enough to trigger scroll or i just found out that the problem is in your `localhost:3000/#something`, it should be `localhost:3000#something` instead
Please try this one

```js
function go() {
  window.location += "#something";
  alert(window.location);
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="go()">scroll</button>
</div>
<h1 id="something">
  My header
</h1>
```